# signal from uniformly moving charge

Tags: charge, radiation, field-theory

As a charge moves, its field changes, and this change can only be propagated outward at the speed of light. Thus the field lines will be curves that keep changing apparent source point and direction. But how can a signal (indicating the source point) be transmitted out without energy? Only accelerating charges radiate energy.

Comment: This is just a retarded electromagnetic potential (again, potential, a work which might be done), so no energy is actually transmitted. Putting a detector (another charge) into the potential field will "activate" the field to move the charge and do some real work, i.e. some energy will be exchanged then only.

Comment: I see. But why does the transfer of info about changing location of a uniformly moving charge to the distant field not require energy, while it does for an accelerating charge? Shd one say the latter energy is not needed to carry the info, it's a separate phenomenon?

Comment: Due to special relativity, a stationary charge has the electric field around, but that field is seen from another moving inertial (i.e. steadily moving) frame of reference as the electromagnetic field. This EM field is self-sustainable in means that the energies contained in its electric and magnetic components are just mutually oscillating without loss of their common energy. In case of acceleration, the frame of reference of the charge is no more inertial at that moment, so some energies have to be adjusted to the new conditions. This adjustment is your radiation.

Comment: Even a slow (non relativistic) moving charge represents a current flow which should generate a magnetic field perpendicular to the radial electric field. Please show the math involved in order for the resulting Poyinting vector being zero or not being able to propagate energy.

Comment: ans. to gox:  I don't see how a moving signal can not be a light wave, and hence transfer energy at a rate equal to the field intensity times the speed of light. That's what light is, a moving change in the field.

Comment: ans. to Jens: You don't need to look at the poynying vector. It's clear that energy is not transmitted by the signal from a charge in uniform motion (fast or slow), since the charge does not lose energy. If it lost energy, it wd not be in uniform motion. We know it is in uniform motion if it is  stationary in its own [inertial] frame, and appears moving only because it is being observed in another inertial frame.

Comment: What if the charge was carried by some device which maintained a uniform motion by compensating for any energy loss?

Comment: Well sure, if energy was radiated by a uniformly moving charge, it wd have to be compensated for continuously from some outside force, but the question is, is radiation emitted by a uniformly moving charge?